# search by substring in documentDB

Tags: c#, search, sql-like, azure-cosmosdb

this is the sample documentDB document,

I want to get all the documents who failed in one or more subjects

I found something like

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM students s 
JOIN c IN s.subjects 
WHERE c.result = "pass"
```

I want to retrieve by using c# code

```
{
  "id": "0066a253-f042-4213-b06e-65b1ea1e49aa",
  "name": "Sunny",
  "rollNo": 123,
  "class": "2nd",
  "section": "B",
  "Department": {
    "name": "CSE",
    "id": "cse",
    "subjects": [
      {
        "id": "subject-1",
        "marksObtained": 66,
        "maxMarks": 100,
        "result": "pass"
      },
      {
        "id": "subject-2",
        "marksObtained": 56,
        "maxMarks": 75,
        "result": "pass"
      },
      {
        "id": "subject-3",
        "marksObtained": 22,
        "maxMarks": 100,
        "result": "fail"
      },
      {
        "id": "subject-4",
        "marksObtained": 36,
        "maxMarks": 50,
        "result": "pass"
      },
      {
        "id": "subject-5",
        "marksObtained": 16,
        "maxMarks": 100,
        "result": "fail"
      }
    ]
  },
  "Type": "Student"
}
```

i tried like this

```
var result = client.CreateDocumentQuery<dynamic>(dc.SelfLink, "SELECT s.id as id,s.Name as Name,s.Age as Age,s.section as section,s.subjects as subjects FROM students s JOIN c IN s.subjects WHERE c.result = \"pass\"").ToList(); 

List<Student> students = new List<Student>(); 
foreach(var std in result) 
{ 
     students.Add((Student)std); 
}
```

Something like above is my code I am getting, but Even I give pa or pas or pass or p or ass or as then also I should get something I need a functionality of LIKE in SQL

Is there any solution for this??
I need LIKE functionality in SQL to retrieve data from documentDB

Comment: Where is your effort ?

Comment: from f in client.CreateDocumentQuery<student>(dc.SelfLink)
                               where f.subjects[0].result == "pass"
                               select f;

Comment: var result = client.CreateDocumentQuery<dynamic>(dc.SelfLink, "SELECT s.id as id,s.Name as Name,s.Age as Age,s.section as section,s.subjects as subjects FROM students s JOIN c IN s.subjects WHERE c.result = \"pass\"").ToList();
                List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
                foreach(var std in result)
                {
                    students.Add((Student)std);
                }
Something like above is my code
I am getting, but Even I give pa or pas or pass or p or ass or as then also I should get
something I need a functionality of LIKE in SQL

Comment: Don't add it as a comment, nobody will read it like this. Add it in the question.

Comment: thanks @mybirthname
I am new for this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update: As of [5/6/15](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/new-documentdb-sql-keywords-operators-and-functions/), DocumentDB added a set of String functions including `STARTSWITH`, `ENDSWITH`, and `CONTAINS`. Please note that most of these functions do not run on the index and will force a scan.**

Wildcards like SQL's LIKE '% %' has not been implemented in DocumentDB *yet*.

Please voice your opinion and vote for this feature on [DocumentDB's feedback forum](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/suggestions/6333414-implement-wildcards-when-searching).

Answer (score 5):

Some new functions have been introduced in the last few months. For you particular case I think you can use:

```
WHERE STARTSWITH(c.result, "p")
```

Comment: Can I use contains?? please share the link about this update

Comment: SELECT food.id,
 food.description,
 food.tags,
 food.foodGroup
FROM food where startswith(food.id, "03"); is not working. any Idea?