# DocumentDB LinQ Request rate is large

Tags: c#, linq, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to use DocumentDB, a small database and trying to do text search on one of the columns using LinQ in C#. When the query is executed, I am getting "request rate is too high" error message and data returning really slow.

Database is set at 400RU. I am still testing the database and I am doing a single request using LinQ.

**Error Message:**

> Operation will be retried after 9707 milliseconds. Current attempt 1,
>   Cumulative delay 00:00:09.7070000 Exception:
>   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.DocumentClientException: Message:
>   {"Errors":["Request rate is large"]}

**Here is my Query:**

```
var feed = from c in _client.CreateDocumentQuery<DataModel.Company>(_collUri, new FeedOptions() { MaxItemCount = 20 })
                            where c.Name.ToLower().Contains(keyword.ToLower())
                            select new { c.CIK, c.Name, Index = c.Name.ToLower().IndexOf(keyword.ToLower()) };
```

**Document structure:**

```
{      
  "Company Name": "ABC Test Company, Inc.",
  "Meta": [],
  "Aux": [
    {
      "file Type": "T",
      "Date posted": "2017-01-20",
      "Filename": "ccc/data/1695034/a.txt"
    }
  ],
  "id": "1695034"
}
```

*`Company.Name` is mapped to `"Company Name"` field in DocumentDB

Answer (score 4):

Any time you manipulate the data in a field before you do a comparison in the "WHERE" part of your query and there is no other more selective clause, you automatically trigger a full table scan (no indexes used). So, `c.Name.ToLower()` is just such a manipulation.

You could work around this issue by storing an additional field with the name already in lower case and using that field in your query.

Comment: Yup - and to add-on, it's helpful to track how much RU a particular request takes. You can find details on how to do this here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34057204/319795

Comment: Added a field and a new Indexing policy of Range on the field. With these changes, STARTSWITH began working, but CONTAINS still getting "Request rate is Large" error. Here is the query: 
SELECT TOP 20 * FROM c where CONTAINS(c.NameIndex, "test")
REQUEST CHARGE: 2313.41 RUs
Any other suggestions please...

Comment: What happens when you switch `CONTAINS` TO `STARTSWITH`? My theory is that `CONTAINS` doesn't use an index. If you really need this sort of text search, then you probably want a text search engine like @Matias suggests below.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to do text searches, I'd recommend using [Azure Search](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/search/) on top of DocumentDB.

You can index the information on DocumentDB with [Indexers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-index-documentdb).

Azure Search would yield a better search experience in these cases (text searching) and it won't impact on your DocumentDB throughput. It has it's own service charge though so it should be taken into consideration. If you application will rely heavily on text search capabilities, it is probably the best choice.

For a more detailed service description, here are some articles that might help:

- [Introdution to Azure Search (Channel9)](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Data-Exposed/Introduction-To-Azure-Search)
- [Streamlining a search experience](https://auth0.com/blog/azure-search-with-aspnetcore/)
- [A hitchhikers guide to Azure Search](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2016/02/02/a-hitchhikers-guide-to-search/)

Comment: I understand that Azure search might work. But for simple low volume applications like my use case, I don't want to create a dependency chain of several services. Isn't the promise if DocumentDB is simplicity? We are NOT even doing complicated queries yet.

Comment: The problem is the Text Search nature of your query and the limitations of DocDB on that field in particular. Like @Larry mentioned, you can try with the `CONTAINS` and `STARTSWITH` operators and see if they help, but they do not use indexes. Please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27740398/search-by-substring-in-documentdb) and add to [this User Request](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/suggestions/6333414-implement-wildcards-when-searching).